# Solenoid Controller Options - No Arduino?

Tags: solenoid

I'm a total beginner looking to do a one time project that involves a solenoid. I basically just need the solenoid to extend on the push of a button (which will be push manually in fairly rapid succession). I.E. I push a button and for however long I hold it down the solenoid remains extended, the second I let go, the solenoid goes retracts. I would love to not deal with an Arduino if that is possible.

I am wondering if I can directly wire the solenoid with a resistor, battery, and a button/switch.

This is the solenoid (https://www.adafruit.com/product/2776) I am thinking of ordering (or possibly the next size up).

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: what does "extend on the push of a button" mean? Try to explain it like "I do this and that happens" to make sure it's clear

Comment: If it isn't a proportional valve etc then a simple switch will do fine, if it can handle the current. If not then put a relay in between.

Comment: yes, a simple circuit works fine. the main advantages to making it more complex (like an MCU, SSR, or relay) would be the ability to use thinner cables on a long run and a cheaper switch. Or automation and all that...

Answer (score 1):

If you have a 5V battery, then you can just wire the solenoid in series with the switch, and it should work.
Just be carefull tu use a switch that can support the current (1.1A at 5V). A switch made for lights will probably be fine (still double check). Small signal buttons (like those in arduino starter kits) might not suport that much curent.

The resistor might be usefull if you have a battery with higher voltage (nb : you will then probably need a power resistor). If your battery has only slightly higher voltage (for example 6V), you can probably get away without resistor : the only risk is the solenoid overheating : start by powerring it for a fraction of second, and check temperature, then increase duration : if it remains reasonable, then the voltage is still OK. Be carefull not to burn your fingers if not (touch first wearing a glove, and if not to hot use your bare fingers : if you can touch continously with bare fingers you are fine).

If you have a bit less voltage (for example 3 AA cells (ie 4.5V) or a fully charged single Lipo Cell (4.2V)), then it will work without resistor, you will just have a bit less mechanical power.

If you use a transtor, a power bank or a voltage converter, then I would recommand adding a diode in paralel to the solenoid (in blocking direction) to avoid damaging the electronics with the voltage spikes caused by the brutal opening of the circuit

Comment: even with just the switch, the diode is still a good idea as it will prolong the life of the switch and reduce radio interferance.

Comment: It's sure that it is better with a diode. But the question was about a "one time project", so for a short use, I don't think it is necessary. If planing prolonged use (or use at the same time than radio devices), then I would recommand it.

Comment: I read "one-time" as meaning bespoke, not indicating a lifespan.